# PHP drop down list that downloads a file from a folder when clicked on

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to create a PHP drop down list that downloads a file from a folder on the server when clicked on. I'm using IIS and using the joomla plugin sourcerer which allows PHP scripts to run on joomla webpages.

I'm currently using this code sample (from a stack exchange post not created by me) and I edited it to work for my own environment.

```
<p>
<select name="s1">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Document</option>
<?php
foreach(glob(dirname(path-to-root-dir) . '\path-to-sub-folder\*') as $filename){
$filename = basename($filename);
echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</p>
```

but I haven't figured out a way to make it so that when a user clicks for example test.txt from the drop down list the browser prompts them to download the selected file. I've seen this done in .asp but I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have less to do with PHP and more to do with JavaScript.  The event of selecting an item in the `select` element is handled by JavaScript.

For example, if you uniquely identify the element with an `id`:

```
<select name="s1" id="s1">
```

Then you can reliably get the element in JavaScript:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById('s1');
```

Now you can bind an event handler to it:

```
selectElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
    // handle the event here
});
```

It looks like you want to *handle* the event by getting the value of the `select` and directing the browser to that value as a URL.  Something like this should get you started:

```
selectElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var fileUrl = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = fileUrl;
});
```

This assumes that the value is actually the correct URL for the file.  If it isn't, you'll need to address that of course.  But the point is that responding to this event and directing the browser to "download the file" is a client-side operation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path-to-sub-folder') as $file)
    {
        if($file->isDot()) continue;
        if($file->isFile())
        {
            $filename = basename($file);
            echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would probably use Mysql/PHPMYADMIN to store the location of the file and its name to then use jquery to load

PHPScript {

```
$con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("Unable to connect to Local DB");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con)or die("Unable to select DB");

// retrive data which you want to export
$query = "SELECT * FROM File_List";
$Options = '<option value="" selected> Please select a file. </option>';
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$Options .= '<option value="'.$Row['FileID'].'">'.$Row['FileName'].'</option> 
';}
echo ' <select id="FileList">'.$Options.'</select> <p id="FileGrab"></p>
<script>
var from = $("#FileList").val();
$("#FileGrab").load("Grab_File.php?Name=" + from);
</script>
';
```

}

Grab_File.php {

```
$ID = $_GET['Name'];
$con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("Unable to connect to Local DB");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con)or die("Unable to select DB");

// retrive data which you want to export
$query = "SELECT * FROM File_List WHERE id='$ID'";
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$Location = $Row['Location'];
$Name = $Row['Name'];

$file = ''.$Location.''.$Name.'';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

}